# Using single slicer to control two pivot tables with different data source in Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssas, pivot-table

I have a problem with slicer in Excel file. In my Excel file I have two worksheets. In the first one, there is a pivot table taking data from OLAP cube and in the second I have a pivot table taking data from another Excel file. I'd like to have one slicer called "Organization" to filter data in both tables. Is it possible?

Kind regards

Answer (score 3):

No - it seems not. Slicers are meant to be used on pivot tables that share the same data source it seems. You should be able to conglomerate your data into one source and create two pivot tables with a shared slicer though.

From Microsoft: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/use-slicers-to-filter-pivottable-data-HA010359466.aspx

> Make a slicer available for use in another PivotTable
>
> 1.Click the slicer that you want to share in another PivotTable. This displays the Slicer Tools, adding an Options tab.
>
> 2.On the Options tab, in the Slicer group, click PivotTable Connections.
>
> 3.In the PivotTable Connections dialog box, select the check box of the PivotTables in which you want the slicer to be available.

Or you could just create one pivot table.

Or you could have a look at this:
[Making all pivot tables on one sheet mimic each other in terms of rows expanding and collapsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352905/making-all-pivot-tables-on-one-sheet-mimic-each-other-in-terms-of-rows-expanding/12357834#12357834)

Good Luck.

Comment: good point. I found it very confusing that sometimes I could control two pivot tables with one slicer and sometimes not - even though I could in both cases specify that the slicer is supposed to influence more than one pivot table. but the difference was that in one case the pivot tables where coming from one and in the other from two sources ... (+1)