# Making all pivot tables on one sheet mimic each other in terms of rows expanding and collapsing for power pivot

Tags: excel, powerpivot

The vba i found on this site for ['Making all pivot tables on one sheet mimic each other in terms of rows expanding and collapsing'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12357834/10068520) works fantastic for a standard pivot table in excel, however, it doesn't work with power pivot, how is this coding modified for power pivot?

Comment: Couldn't you use slicers instead of code?  [Contexturesblog](https://contexturesblog.com/archives/2011/03/07/filter-multiple-pivot-tables-with-excel-2010-slicers/) has pretty good instructions on how to do it.

Comment: No, i'm using slicers, but for what i need to do the tables need to open to the next level together.  The code on here is perfect for the principle but also have connected tables so has to be in power pivot.